# Maven dependency version mismatch issue - resolving outdated version of dependency from repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-metadata

When I try to build my Maven project in Eclipse, I'm getting this build failure message:

```
[INFO] Checking for transitive/resolved version mismatches.
[INFO] com.company.etc:artifact-name:
[INFO]     required: 1.5
[INFO]     resolved: 1.3
```

My POM file is requesting version 1.5 of this artifact, so that part is correct. But on the repository listed, versions 1.3, 1.4, and 1.5 are all available, with the correct maven-metadata.xml file in the root directory as well. Simply changing my POM file requirements to the older version is not an option, since I need the features in the newest version of the artifact.

I'm really stumped here. Is there anything I'm overlooking that might cause Maven to **resolve a lower version number than what is actually available on the repo server**?

Comment: that's not build failure message, it's an info message. that is not failing your build as such. Also, picking lower version is standard maven behaviour in some cases - it uses closes-first matching, which will take the lower one if that is closest. Can you specify your pom?

Comment: I guess I should specify - I have it set to fail the build if there are version mismatches. Is there anyway to have it pick the higher version?

Comment: Yes, by having explicit versions in pom files in correct places. But you would need to provide your pom details to tell more exact instructions.

Comment: also, `mvn dependency:tree` output would be helpful

Comment: mvn dependency:tree helped me figure it out, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possible solutions that I found for this issue:

**The first one** is to specify an exact version requirement, or "hard requirement" for a specific version of a dependency, as shown below:

```
<version>[1.5]</version>
```

instead of:

```
<version>1.5</version>
```

**The second one** is to use the `mvn dependency:tree` Maven command to see exactly what dependencies are being pulled in, and in what hierarchy. In my case, this solved my problem when I noticed that one dependency was actually pulling in an older version of another dependency, as a sub-dependency. Despite the fact that the sub-dependency was specified on its own elsewhere in the POM, Maven used the older version that was pulled in as a sub-dependency. Sounds confusing I know, but either way, `mvn dependency:tree` should show if a dependency is being pulled in unknowingly, or at an unspecified version.